# Use NewWizard-Dialog in e4

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I want to use in Eclipse 4.X the NewWizard-Dialog `org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizard`, so far I know it is not possible. Because the NewWizard-Dialog using some stuff from the old Eclispe 3.X environment.

To create a normal Wizard I am using also some old Code, but this is working. Also I declare the Wizards I have defined in my `plugin.xml` as an Extension Point. So all code is the same, but the NewWizard-Dialog is not working. Is there some third-Party implementation out there (I didn't find something)? Or can I use the NewWizard-Dialog too?

## Edit

I want to have this Dialog in my application: As far I known, this Dialog is the NewWizard-Dialog in Eclipse 3.X
[image]

Comment: I am not clear what you are doing. Are you writing your own New Wizard or trying to use the 3.x wizard?

Comment: With my picture I want to say, that I want to use the special NewWizard-Dialog, with contains all Wizard that I have define in my "old" plugin.xml as an ExtensionPoint

Comment: The existing New Wizard is very dependent on Eclipse 3.x code you won't be able to use this in a pure e4 application. You will have to use Eclipse 4 with the 3.x compatibility layer.